# Hibernate one to one mapping on composite foreign key and primary key in single table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have a Catagory table, with composite primary key and foreign key. My table structure is like

```
CREATE TABLE CATAGORY (
  CATAGORY_ID int(11) NOT NULL,
  CATAGORY_NAME varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  VERSION int(11) NOT NULL,
  PARENT_ID  int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CATAGORY_ID,VERSION)
);

ALTER TABLE CATAGORY ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_ID, VERSION) REFERENCES CATAGORY (CATAGORY_ID, VERSION);
```

and I want a ORM mapping with Catagory class like this

```
public class Catagory {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CatagoryPk pk ;
    @Column(name="CATAGORY_NAME")
    private String  catagoryName;

    private Catagory parentId;

    private List<Catagory> childs ;                 

}
@Embeddable
public class CatagoryPk {
    @Column(name="VERSION")
    private Integer version;
    @Column(name="CATEGORY_ID")
    private Integer catagoryId;
}
```

Now how to annotate

```
private Catagory parentId;  
private List<Catagory> childs ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="VERSION", referencedColumnName="VERSION"),
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName="CATAGORY_ID")
})
@ManyToOne
private Catagory parentId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="parentId")
private List<Catagory> childs;
```

or version with `@IdClass` instead of `@EmbeddableId` (tested with Eclipselink 2.2.1):

```
public class CatagoryPk implements Serializable {

    private Integer version;
    private Integer catagoryId;

    public CatagoryPk() {
    }

    public CatagoryPk(Integer version, Integer catagoryId) {
        this.version = version;
        this.catagoryId = catagoryId;
    }
}

@Entity
@IdClass(CatagoryPk.class)
public class Catagory {
    @Column(name="VERSION")
    @Id private Integer version;
    @Column(name="CATAGORY_ID")
    @Id private Integer catagoryId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="VERSION", referencedColumnName="VERSION", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName="CATAGORY_ID")
    })
    private Catagory parentId;
}
```

Comment: It is showing following error Repeated column in mapping for entity: Category column: VERSION (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: Yes, I figured it out eventually too during testing. Not trivial question though.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [guide](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-self-join-annotations-one-to-many-mapping/). You'll have to use @ManyToOne and @OneToMany annotations.

Comment: I am not able to find the annotation for single table