# Hibernate referencing a primary key that does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, oracle12c

I'm getting the following error when attempting to deploy an application that uses hibernate:

> Foreign key (FK2e496501ee5lgk3viylwiicsa:MANAGED_APP_TO_CON_TO_SRUCT [MANAGED_APP_TO_CONTACT_ID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (MANAGED_APPLICATION_TO_CONTACT [CONTACT_ID,MANAGED_APPLICATION_ID])

But I'm not sure what key hibernate is referencing here. As you can see from the model below produced by Oracle SQL Developer, there is no composite primary key on `CONTACT_ID, MANAGED_APPLICATION_ID`. The primary key of `MANAGED_APPLICATION_TO_CONTACT` is on the sequenced column `MANAGED_APP_TO_CONTACT_ID`, which is the column referenced in the foreign key.

[image]

So, I am led to believe that the issue lies somewhere in the JPA mappings in my entities. Below are the relevant entities (note that I have opted to post the full entities instead of a minimal example, in case the issue lies somewhere that I am not expecting in my entities):

**ManagedApplicationToContact:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MANAGED_APPLICATION_TO_CONTACT", schema = "UAM")
public class ManagedApplicationToContact implements java.io.Serializable {


    private Long managedAppToContactId;
    private ManagedApplication managedApplication;
    private Contact contact;
    private Long lastUpdatedBy;
    private Date lastUpdated;

    public ManagedApplicationToContact() {
    }

    public ManagedApplicationToContact(final ManagedApplication managedApplication, final Contact contact, final Long lastUpdatedBy, final Date lastUpdated) {
        this.managedApplication = managedApplication;
        this.contact = contact;
        this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    @SequenceGenerator(name = "generator", sequenceName = "UAM.SEQ_MANAGED_APP_TO_CONTACT", initialValue = 0, allocationSize = 1)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "MANAGED_APP_TO_CONTACT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
    public Long getManagedAppToContactId() {
        return this.managedAppToContactId;
    }

    public void setManagedAppToContactId(final Long managedAppToContactId) {
        this.managedAppToContactId = managedAppToContactId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MANAGED_APPLICATION_ID", nullable = false)
    public ManagedApplication getManagedApplication() {
        return this.managedApplication;
    }

    public void setManagedApplication(final ManagedApplication managedApplication) {
        this.managedApplication = managedApplication;
    }

    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_BY", nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
    public Long getLastUpdatedBy() {
        return this.lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedBy(final Long lastUpdatedBy) {
        this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED", length = 7)
    public Date getLastUpdated() {
        return this.lastUpdated;
    }

    public void setLastUpdated(final Date lastUpdated) {
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "CONTACT_ID", referencedColumnName = "CONTACT_ID", nullable = false)
    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(final Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}
```

**ManagedAppToConToStruct:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MANAGED_APP_TO_CON_TO_STRUCT", schema = "UAM")
public class ManagedAppToConToStruct {
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "generator", sequenceName = "UAM.MAN_APP_TO_CON_TO_STRUCT_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "MANAGED_APP_TO_CONTACT_ID", referencedColumnName = "MANAGED_APP_TO_CONTACT_ID", nullable = false)
    private ManagedApplicationToContact managedApplicationToContact;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="STRUCTURE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Structure structure;

    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED")
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdated;

    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_BY")
    @Basic
    private Long lastUpdatedBy;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ManagedApplicationToContact getManagedApplicationToContact() {
        return managedApplicationToContact;
    }

    public void setManagedApplicationToContact(final ManagedApplicationToContact managedApplicationToContact) {
        this.managedApplicationToContact = managedApplicationToContact;
    }

    public Structure getStructure() {
        return structure;
    }

    public void setStructure(final Structure structure) {
        this.structure = structure;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getLastUpdated() {
        return lastUpdated;
    }

    public void setLastUpdated(final LocalDateTime lastUpdated) {
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    public Long getLastUpdatedBy() {
        return lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedBy(final Long lastUpdatedBy) {
        this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
    }
}
```

I even used IntelliJ IDE's built in entity generation feature to build these entities from the database schema, and it produced the same mappings. I added a Hibernate JPA facet to my project, and IntelliJ indicates that all of the mapping is done correctly - so I'm seriously stumped here.

---

**EDIT:** Adding create statements for the tables.

**MANAGED_APPLICATION_TO_CONTACT:** (this one was generated from Oracle SQL Developer, as I don't have the original script that was run)

```
CREATE TABLE "UAM"."MANAGED_APPLICATION_TO_CONTACT" 
   (    "MANAGED_APP_TO_CONTACT_ID" NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CONTACT_ID" NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MANAGED_APPLICATION_ID" NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LAST_UPDATED_BY" NUMBER, 
    "LAST_UPDATED" DATE, 
     CONSTRAINT "MANAGE_APPLICATION_CONTACT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("MANAGED_APP_TO_CONTACT_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "UAM"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "MANAGED_APPLICATION_TO_CO_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("MANAGED_APPLICATION_ID")
      REFERENCES "UAM"."MANAGED_APPLICATION" ("MANAGED_APPLICATION_ID") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "UAM" ;
```

**MANAGED_APP_TO_CON_TO_STRUCT:** (this is the actual script that was used to create the table)

```
CREATE TABLE UAM.MANAGED_APP_TO_CON_TO_STRUCT (
  ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  MANAGED_APP_TO_CONTACT_ID NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
  STRUCTURE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  LAST_UPDATED TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  LAST_UPDATED_BY NUMBER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT MAN_APP_TO_CON_TO_STRUCT_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT MAN_APP_TO_CON_TO_STRUCT_FK01 FOREIGN KEY (MANAGED_APP_TO_CONTACT_ID) REFERENCES UAM.MANAGED_APPLICATION_TO_CONTACT (MANAGED_APP_TO_CONTACT_ID),
  CONSTRAINT MAN_APP_TO_CON_TO_STRUCT_FK02 FOREIGN KEY (STRUCTURE_ID) REFERENCES HIERARCHY.STRUCTURE (STRUCTURE_ID),
  CONSTRAINT MAN_APP_TO_CON_TO_STRUCT_FK03 FOREIGN KEY (LAST_UPDATED_BY) REFERENCES MCT.CONTACT (CONTACT_ID)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UAM.MAN_APP_TO_CON_TO_STRUCT_IDX01 ON UAM.MANAGED_APP_TO_CON_TO_STRUCT (MANAGED_APP_TO_CONTACT_ID, STRUCTURE_ID);
```

---

**EDIT:** Adding full stack trace.

```
2017-01-06 15:34:42.834 ERROR [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader:353 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MCT' defined in com.myproject.JpaConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK2e496501ee5lgk3viylwiicsa:MANAGED_APP_TO_CON_TO_STRUCT [MANAGED_APP_TO_CONTACT_ID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (MANAGED_APPLICATION_TO_CONTACT [CONTACT_ID,MANAGED_APPLICATION_ID])
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4990)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1763)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$240(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/1638143133.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK2e496501ee5lgk3viylwiicsa:MANAGED_APP_TO_CON_TO_STRUCT [MANAGED_APP_TO_CONTACT_ID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (MANAGED_APPLICATION_TO_CONTACT [CONTACT_ID,MANAGED_APPLICATION_ID])
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1888)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1808)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1627)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

---

**EDIT:**

Also wanted to note that the `ManagedApplicationToContact` entity was working perfectly fine before adding `ManagedAppToConToStruct`.

Comment: Can you please provide the full exception with stacktrace instead of only the exception message? It might be interesting to see which component in the chain exactly spews out this error. Also: it may be better to generate the SQL create statements rather than the visual diagrams. You want the least interpreted view of what is involved.

Comment: @Gimby added stacktrace and create statements

Comment: Normally you're not supposed to reuse the name in `SequenceGenerator`, but that's just an additional problem that you would have run into later. It's not your current problem. I'm still looking to see what is missing. Other problems include `referencedColumnName` in `JoinColumn` is supposed to have the name of the field on the other side, not the sql-name of the column.

Comment: @coladict Interesting, I've always used the same name for `SequenceGenerator`s and have never had any issues with it

Comment: Because of the order of processing of annotated classes in Hibernate, that's not an issue, so long as you declare them both in the class, but if you try and migrate to EclipseLink it will crash and burn. I think I found something that might help you. That UNIQUE constraint is treated as a primary key, even though it's not officially one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696358/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-on-composite-foreign-key-and-primary-key-in-single

Comment: @coladict thought about that, but it is complaining about a primary key on `CONTACT_ID, MANAGED_APPLICATION_ID` in the table `MANAGED_APPLICATION_TO_CONTACT`, and there is no unique constraint on those columns in that table.

Comment: You are mixing property/method level annotations and field level annotations - albeit in different classes - however that would be the first thing I would fix. See section 2.2.2.2 http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/ Note
*The placement of annotations within a class hierarchy has to be consistent (either field or on property) to be able to determine the default access type. It is recommended to stick to one single annotation placement strategy throughout your whole application.*

Comment: @AlanHay I made them all method level, but still get the same error

Comment: @Gimby that is just the default status for the NOT NULL constraint. `NOT NULL ENABLE` is the same thing as `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Nope, connecting to the correct db and the only mappings I use are annotation based in the entity classes themselves.

Comment: Also opened up a [topic on the hibernate forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1043893) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that I had this mapping in the `Contact` entity that was using `MANAGED_APPLICATION_TO_CONTACT` as a join table to retrieve the `ManagedApplication` records tied to the `Contact`, which was causing hibernate to assume the primary key on `CONTACT_ID,MANAGED_APPLICATION_ID`:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "MANAGED_APPLICATION_TO_CONTACT", schema = "UAM",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CONTACT_ID",
                referencedColumnName = "CONTACT_ID",
                nullable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "MANAGED_APPLICATION_ID",
                referencedColumnName = "MANAGED_APPLICATION_ID",
                nullable = false)})
@OrderBy("name asc")
public Set<ManagedApplication> getManagedApplications() {
    return this.managedApplications;
}

public void setManagedApplications(final Set<ManagedApplication> managedApplications) {
    this.managedApplications = managedApplications;
}
```

To correct this, I got rid of this mapping and made it into a transient method, which just pulls the `ManagedApplication` records out of the already properly mapped `managedApplicationToContacts` records.

```
@Transient
public Set<ManagedApplication> getManagedApplications() {
    if (this.managedApplications.isEmpty()) {
        this.managedApplications = this.managedApplicationToContacts.stream()
                .map(ManagedApplicationToContact::getManagedApplication)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
    return this.managedApplications;
}
```